# Determine filter status on a xamDataGrid

Tags: wpf, filter, infragistics, xamdatagrid

In a WPF app I'm developing I'd like to programmatically determine if a xamDataGrid has any filters configured or not.

I've configured an export function to Excel and would like to do a quick check to determine if a filter is active or not, if a filter is active then I'll present the user with the option to export filtered rows or not...

I can't find any suitable class members.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer guys n girls...

```
    var activeFilterCount = xamDataGrid1.FieldLayouts[0].RecordFilters.Sum(recordFilter => recordFilter.Conditions.Count);
```

Answer (score 1):

A ***`XamDataGrid`*** can have **more than one field layout *(hierarchical structure)***. In that case you need to consider all `FieldLayouts` not just **the first one**. So the **complete solution** is:

```
 public bool AreFiltersActive()
 {
   int activeFilterCount = 0;
   foreach (FieldLayout f in xamDataGrid.FieldLayouts)
   {
     activeFilterCount+= f.RecordFilters.Sum(recordFilter => recordFilter.Conditions.Count);
     //retrieve filter count per layout
   }        
   return activeFilterCount > 0;
   //If any fieldlayout has any filter active then the sum will be more than 0
 }
```

> ***There is a reason why `Filters` are stored per `FieldLayout` in `XamDataGrid`.***
>
> In the earlier version they are stored in `RecordManger`
>   against the `grid`. So it's the complete solution to iterate the
>   all `FieldLayouts`.

**Like Below Grid:`Multiple Layout and Filters can be applied on every Layout/Level`**

[image: XamDataGrid with multiple layouts]